# Save Image from RSS Feed to Django Image Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup, rss

I have a model like this:

```
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="news/", blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Then, I pulled the image url from RSS feed using BeautifulSoup4:

```
#views.py
def pull_feeds(request, pk):
    source = Autoblogging.objects.get(pk=pk)
    url = requests.get(source.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")

    cover = soup.find('media:content')['url']
    Post.objects.create(cover=cover)
```

The content feed is something like this

```
<media:content url="https://travelcommunication.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Raffles-Hotels-Bring-Legendary-Hospitality-Experience-to-Romantic-Udaipur-TRAVELINDEX-TOP25HOTELS-500x300.jpg" width="500" height="300" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

But it only save the url, not the image file.
How to save the actual image file instead of url to that image?

Answer (score 0):

You can send another `GET` request for the image and write the response to a file:

```
...
image = requests.get(cover)
with open("image.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(image.content)
```

Comment: ok i get the idea, but how to save it to my model?

Comment: @penk Sorry, I won't be able to help you, I'm not familiar with Django.

Comment: ok no problem, thanks for answering